# Three.js webgl + javascript LAG on client side

Tags: javascript, php, three.js

We have some 3ds boxes in Three.js and we put some texture on them.
The texture of the boxes are generated by php.

loader.load ('textures / phppics.php')

The connection to the server is fast, but it takes at least 1 second, but often it can take up to 10 seconds for the image to appear on the box. During this time the 3d boxes are black.
The php code is minimal, it can't slow down. The three.js runs fast.

Where and for what reason is taking so long to put the texture on the boxes?
Why is the huge lag?

[image: here is how its looks like]

Comment: You did not provide any code so there's no way for us to help with that.

Comment: As with debugging, you could inspect the network tab and check how quickly it loads the file you're talking about. If there is a lot of time between the file being finished loading and it appearing in the scene, it could indicate that it takes that long for the gpu to render the texture. Downscaling it would then be advised.

Comment: What are the dimensions and file size of the image?